# Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

Hi Community of Stackoverflow,

I am facing a problem here with my shell script that I am designing...

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
clear
echo "-----------------------------
-----------"
echo "***************Main Menu****************"
echo "----------------------------------------"
echo "1. Backup Word Document"
echo "2. Backup Spreadsheet"
echo "3. Backup Picture"
echo "4. Restore Word Documents"
echo "5. Restore Spreadsheet"
echo "6. Restore Picture"
echo "7. EXIT"

echo "----------------------------------------"
pause
echo -n "Enter your menu choice [1-7]:"
read yourch
case $yourch in
1) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.doc /WP/ ; read ;;

1) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

2) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.xls /EXCEL/ ; read ;;

2) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

3) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.jpg /PICS/ ; read ;;

3) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

4) echo ; tar xvzf /WP/*.doc ; read ;;
5) echo ; tar xvzf /EXCEL/*.xls ; read ;;
6) echo ; tar xvzf /PICS/*.jpg ; read ;;
7) exit 0 ;;

*) echo "Please press a number between 1 to 7";

esac
done
```

A error displays 'cript: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token 'in 'cript: line 21: 'case $yourch

Does anyone know how to by pass this error? Basically what im trying to do is be able to back up a set of files with the file name ".doc" and place them in a backup folder. I can then restore the files from this folder to another folder.

Comment: Try running the script with `sh -vx yourscript.sh`

Comment: What is wrong with rdiff_backup (http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) or even vanilla rsync?

Comment: I did that and it run the script until the line that reads

Comment: When I've deleted `pause` it works without any warning (`pause` was unknown by bash) http://ideone.com/jwIyT

Comment: case $yourch in       Then it stops, the problem is with this line of code

Comment: Please edit your question title to something more specific.

Comment: Why this is working alright on my linux? Except for the pause command.

Comment: I would guess this is because you're using /bin/sh as the interpreter, not /bin/bash or /usr/bin/bash (or wherever your bash interpreter lives).

Answer (score 2):

This runs for me on RHEL 4 ES using /bin/sh as the interpreter.  However, the case statement will execute only the first match.  So where you have two lines to execute for each of options 1, 2 and 3, only the first one is ever executed.  So instead of...

```
1) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.doc /WP/ ; read ;;
1) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;
```

...you may want something more like this:

```
1) echo
   tar -cvf /Files/*.doc /WP/
   echo Today is `date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1`
   read -p "Press <enter> to continue..." ;;
```

Depending on your interpreter, you may also have a problem that your `*)` case does not end in `;;`.

However, the first of these suggestions is debugging a different problem and the second is a long shot.  If you edited this in Windows and copied over in a paste buffer, you may also have an incorrect line-end in Line 21 (and possibly more below).  The fix for that is to run the `dos2unix` command against the script - i.e. `dos2unix /path/to/script.sh`.